# How to cycle multiple forms in one page and retain same submit button in .NET core mvc?

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I'm building a asp.net mvc web app, with razor pages to make things easier, and I ran into a bit of a snag because of my UI design.

I need to have multiple forms that can to cycled through by the user in a bootstrap navigation element. these forms are all unique, but they all have a 'comments' element (textbox and button) in a separate element to the right that serves as the submit button for the form.

[image: UI design]

Right now, I have both 'cards', rfi and knowledgebase, in one form with the comments element. When the user clicks submit on the comments element, is submits both cards, rfi and knowledgebase. I need the current form the user is looking at to be submitted when they click submit the form. Is there any way to do this? Should I use partial views?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <!--<div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container col-sm-8">
            <div class="card form-nav-bar">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#rfi">RFI</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#kBase">Knowledge Base</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <!--RFI card-->
                <div id="rfi" class="card container box-shadow tab-pane active">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <h4>
                                    Consumer Information:
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field col-sm-4">
                                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.RFIModel.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = " " } })
                                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.RFIModel.FirstName)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.RFIModel.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                . . .
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Knowledge Base card-->
                <div id="kBase" class="card container tab-pane">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        . . .
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Summary Modal-->
        <div class="container col-sm-4" role="dialog" id="Comments-Modal">
            <div class="modal-content box-shadow">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Summary</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <!--<label for="Comments"> </label>
                            <textarea type="text" id="Comments" class="md-textarea form-control" mdbInput></textarea>-->
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.RFIModel.Comments)
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.RFIModel.Comments, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = " ", type = "text" }, @class = "md-textarea form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.RFIModel.Comments, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think you can use js and ajax to reference the partial view dynamically:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <!--<div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container col-sm-8">
            <div class="card form-nav-bar">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a id="rfiLink" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#rfi">RFI</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a id="kBaseLink" class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#kBase">Knowledge Base</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="rfi" class="card container box-shadow tab-pane active">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <h4>
                                    Consumer Information:
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field col-sm-4">
                                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.RFIModel.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = " " } })
                                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.RFIModel.FirstName)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.RFIModel.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                . . .
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Summary Modal-->
        <div class="container col-sm-4" role="dialog" id="Comments-Modal">
            <div class="modal-content box-shadow">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Summary</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <!--<label for="Comments"> </label>
                            <textarea type="text" id="Comments" class="md-textarea form-control" mdbInput></textarea>-->
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.RFIModel.Comments)
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.RFIModel.Comments, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = " ", type = "text" }, @class = "md-textarea form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.RFIModel.Comments, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}

@section scripts{ 
<script>
    $("#rfiLink").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "Home/GetRFI",
            success: function (data) {
                $(".tab-content").empty();
                $(".tab-content").html(data);
            }
        })
    })

    $("#kBaseLink").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "Home/GetkBase",
            success: function (data) {
                $(".tab-content").empty();
                $(".tab-content").html(data);
            }
        })
    })
</script>
}
```

Define the corresponding method in the controller to return to the partial view:

```
public IActionResult GetRFI()
{
    return PartialView();
}

public IActionResult GetkBase()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will do exactly that, but is it possible to avoid ajax and jquery? Can i do the same with event listeners and query selectors?